# How to include images in LaTeX large document, while collaborating on Git

Tags: graphics, texstudio, git

I am currently working with a team to create a large latex report document (over 200 pages) where we need to include many images. We are supposed to use Git as version control to collaborate better. (Bitbuckets as remote repo). My question is how we can share images through Git, should I create a separate folder on the remote repo and ask the team members to manually insert the images there... or should we push the images every time we push code?

technical details: I have installed TeXstudio, on Windows.

Comment: It isn't so clear what you are asking, you can treat images just as you do tex source, the folder structure is just personal choice, neither git nor latex have any special requirements.

Comment: lets say I wrote a chapter.tex and insterted pictures inside. now I want to push it to remote repo. obviously I have to push both chapter.tex and image.png separatelly. I want to understand, how my colleague will be able to pull the code and compile it with respective images, without extra struggle?

Comment: a git push pushes the state of the repository you don't really push indvidual files so if the tex and images are added, and you push  they will appear for a coworker when they pull

Comment: It is still bit unclear for me, in my latex file i am indicating image path like this: \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./img/tree.png}  - img is a local folder where I keep pictures. how I have to push the code so that others can pull it with pictures? 
should i push /img folder as well ?

Comment: images are no different to tex, if you have `\input{chapter1/abc.tex}`  you need to add `chapter1/abc.tex` to the repository.If you have `\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./img/tree.png}` you need to add `./img/tree.png` to the repository. The way you, git and latex interact with the files is the same

Comment: Thanks ! I will try that out